# Run one program from another, Raspberry Pi 2 Windows 10 IoT

Tags: raspberry-pi2, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core

I spent several hours to find answer for my question. I am so tired, so I give up and ask You for help.

Is there any way to check installed programs on raspberry pi (with windows 10 iot) from c# code?
I need to do simple ListView with installed programs and run if one is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by 'programs'? There should only be one UWP app installed on the pi at one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought - the Win 10 Core has a browser/web server interface.
http://...:8080

There is a menu option for listing all the loaded/installed apps on the RPI2.

Can you run a network trace to see the call the browser page is making to get the list of apps?

http://minwinpc:8080/api/resourcemanager/processes
(you maybe prompted to login - I wasnt)

This what I see from my machine.

```
{
"Processes": [
{
"CPUUsage": 96.289954,
"ImageName": "System Idle Process",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 8192,
"ProcessId": 0,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 0,
"WorkingSetSize": 8192
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "System",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 8192,
"ProcessId": 4,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 1404928,
"WorkingSetSize": 65536
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "smss.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 110592,
"ProcessId": 228,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 3330048,
"WorkingSetSize": 765952
},
{
"AppName": "IoTCoreDefaultApp",
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "IoTCoreDefaultApp.exe",
"PackageFullName": "IoTCoreDefaultApp_5.0.0.0_arm__kwmcxzszfer2y",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 4927488,
"ProcessId": 244,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "MINWINPC\\DefaultAccount",
"VirtualSize": 183427072,
"WorkingSetSize": 33046528
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 811008,
"ProcessId": 272,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 29102080,
"WorkingSetSize": 4833280
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "csrss.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 253952,
"ProcessId": 416,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 12075008,
"WorkingSetSize": 1548288
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "wininit.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 421888,
"ProcessId": 472,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 14802944,
"WorkingSetSize": 2813952
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "services.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 1163264,
"ProcessId": 516,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 10252288,
"WorkingSetSize": 3682304
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "lsass.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 1830912,
"ProcessId": 540,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 28164096,
"WorkingSetSize": 7823360
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "dwm.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 16900096,
"ProcessId": 608,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "Window Manager\\DWM-0",
"VirtualSize": 68108288,
"WorkingSetSize": 25849856
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 1437696,
"ProcessId": 660,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 33079296,
"WorkingSetSize": 8138752
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 1028096,
"ProcessId": 700,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE",
"VirtualSize": 19726336,
"WorkingSetSize": 4333568
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 3219456,
"ProcessId": 800,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\LOCAL SERVICE",
"VirtualSize": 44740608,
"WorkingSetSize": 9203712
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 3878912,
"ProcessId": 836,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 69656576,
"WorkingSetSize": 15163392
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 2367488,
"ProcessId": 868,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 53243904,
"WorkingSetSize": 9957376
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "msvsmon.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 262144,
"ProcessId": 888,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "MINWINPC\\DefaultAccount",
"VirtualSize": 23502848,
"WorkingSetSize": 1650688
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 2801664,
"ProcessId": 896,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\LOCAL SERVICE",
"VirtualSize": 94810112,
"WorkingSetSize": 10928128
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "SearchIndexer.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 2387968,
"ProcessId": 908,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 66920448,
"WorkingSetSize": 7434240
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "RuntimeBroker.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 806912,
"ProcessId": 928,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "MINWINPC\\DefaultAccount",
"VirtualSize": 22798336,
"WorkingSetSize": 5750784
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 2805760,
"ProcessId": 1016,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE",
"VirtualSize": 41480192,
"WorkingSetSize": 9691136
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "msvsmon.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 266240,
"ProcessId": 1068,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "MINWINPC\\DefaultAccount",
"VirtualSize": 18898944,
"WorkingSetSize": 1466368
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 557056,
"ProcessId": 1104,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\LOCAL SERVICE",
"VirtualSize": 16863232,
"WorkingSetSize": 3424256
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorking`enter code here`Set": 2711552,
"ProcessId": 1256,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\LOCAL SERVICE",
"VirtualSize": 41779200,
"WorkingSetSize": 8491008
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "ebootpinger.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 274432,
"ProcessId": 1372,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 9142272,
"WorkingSetSize": 1241088
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "ftpd.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 163840,
"ProcessId": 1396,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 8114176,
"WorkingSetSize": 1019904
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "sihost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 3575808,
"ProcessId": 1416,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "MINWINPC\\DefaultAccount",
"VirtualSize": 69918720,
"WorkingSetSize": 20426752
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "WebB.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 1523712,
"ProcessId": 1504,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 25554944,
"WorkingSetSize": 5910528
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 4005888,
"ProcessId": 1560,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 72216576,
"WorkingSetSize": 13217792
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 540672,
"ProcessId": 1592,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 16191488,
"WorkingSetSize": 3182592
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 802816,
"ProcessId": 1644,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 34844672,
"WorkingSetSize": 5726208
},
{
"CPUUsage": 0,
"ImageName": "svchost.exe",
"PrivateWorkingSet": 1015808,
"ProcessId": 1752,
"SessionId": 0,
"UserName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
"VirtualSize": 29413376,
"WorkingSetSize": 5304320
}
]
}
```

HTH,

Mick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's not exactly what I need but it gives me some ideas.